# Changing Browser url when paritial page is loading with id? is this possible?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing a project in `MVC4`.

I have a controller named Resources and it has two actions Index and ResourceDetails(This generate a partial page). Based on the links in index page ResourceDetails page is changed in the index page. I use the following code for that.

```
    $(function () {
        $('.detail').click(function () {
            $('#rescontent').load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    });



   @foreach(var Item in Model)
    {                      
     <li> @Html.ActionLink(Item.Res_NA, "ResourceDetails", "Resources", new { id = Item.Id }, new    { @class = "detail" })</li>
     }


 <div id="rescontent">
 @Html.Action("ResourceDetails")
</div>
```

My problem is that i want to get the browser url with particular id like Resources/ResorcesDetails/id
How can i write this. Please help me. My conroller is

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
           return View(new Resources());
    }
    public ActionResult ResourceDetails(int id = 1)
    {
        ResourceItems re = new Resources().GetResDetails(id);
        return PartialView(re);
    }
```

Comment: You want to redirect your page to `ResourceDetails` page on click on the ActionLink right?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)Item.Res_NA, "ResourceDetails", "Resources", new { id = Item.Id }, new { @class = "detail" })
```

Or

```
<a href='ResourceDetails/@Item.Id'>@Item.Res_NA</a>
```

this redirect to your resource and your browser url look like this   `Resources/ResorcesDetails/id`